# fact table is being populated with too many records

Tags: oracle

there are 62000 records in my fact table which is not correct because I only have six records in my time dim, 240 records in my student dim and 140 records in my placement dim, does it have something to do with my where clause any help would be mostly appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO fact_placements (
    report_id,
    no_of_placements,
    no_of_students,
    fk1_time_id,
    fk2_placement_id,
    fk3_student_id )
SELECT
    fact_seq.nextval,
    no_of_placements,
    no_of_students,
    time_id,
    placement_id,
    student_id
FROM
    time_dim,
    placement_dim,
    student_dim 
WHERE
    placement_dim.year = time_dim.year AND
    student_dim.year = time_dim.year;
```

Comment: Your query is simply selecting rows from the table and duplicating them in another table. tell us exactly what you're trying to do..

Comment: You need to show more of your code. There's not enough there for us to help.

Comment: is there a way to inner join those 3 tables? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp i.e. are there any relationships between those 3 tables? or maybe use some grouping perhaps

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do a cartesian join i.e. without any WHERE clause, you will get less than 140 (placement) * 240 (student) * 6 (time) = 201600 fact records. Your current SQL uses the year column in the 3 tables to join, this is filtering down the records to the 62000 you are getting.

Your question title says that even this is "too many". If that is the case, then you would need to understand the granularity of your dimensions and the fact before joining these on any criteria. Are these all at the "year" level, if so do you have 1 record per year in each of these tables and no duplicates based on year?

If not, you might need to re-think the fact tables granularity or alternatively would need to join unique records based on year in each dimension to get the actual (less) number of records you are expecting, which can also be done by summarizing these tables based on year.

Ideally the fact table contains the combinations of the dimension keys with additional column i.e. the factual metrics (in this case no_of_placements and no_of_students). But depending on the available data not all combinations will be present in the fact table.

Also you might want to change the SQL syntax to use the INNER JOIN clause instead of the implied joins using the commas between table names in the FROM clause, as shown below

```
 FROM time_dim
INNER 
 JOIN placement_dim
   ON placement_dim.year = time_dim.year
INNER 
 JOIN student_dim 
   ON placement_dim.year = student_dim.year
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no relationship between placement and student that's why you have so many records.

Your query is saying: **Give me all the students and all the placements where year is the same.**

I'm not sure that's what you want. What is really strange here is that you are loading a fact table with dimensions tables.

Comment: i want to find out how many how many students go on placements each year